# PreTranslateMessage' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition

Tags: mfc

In a `CDialog` class I needed to override
Using VS2008 I've done this several times before using the IDE properties/override  and it adds adding this code:

```cpp
virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg); // in the header file

BOOL CMyTestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) // in the cpp file
{
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

The compiler complains with these messages:

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
error C2065: 'pMsg' : undeclared identifier
error C2448: 'CMy_TestDlg::PreTranslateMessage' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
```

If I removed the `PreTranslateMessage` stuff the project compiles and runs as expected.

As the IDE added the override code I'm confused as to what I did wrong, so

I made another simpler Project and did the override in it, and it compiles OK.

Comment: Since you clicked the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link, I assume that you have a question. What is it?

Comment: As the IDE added the override code I'm confused as to what I did wrong ?

Comment: Are the class definitions proper? 
C2059: error is caused by a token.
C2448: error is caused by an old-style C formal parameter list. 

From just the part of code you have provided, things look OK and should compile.

Are you missing any standard include files? PreTranslateMessage is used by controls and class derived from CWinApp. Is your class inheriting/deriving from such a control?

Are you doing something like:  

   **`class CmyClass : public XYZ`**

where XYZ is not a CWinApp derivative?

Comment: The original class CMy_TestDlg : public CDialog code was generated by the IDE when I started the project.

Comment: The original class CMy_TestDlg : public CDialog code was generated by the IDE when I started the project. using #include "afxwin.h"
#include "afxcmn.h" (again added by the IDE) . I've compared the new project I made which compiles OK and the includes are the same as.  I'll have to step by step move the other code to the next project until it stops compiling. Thanks for the suggestions.